# How to avoid not-safe context operations in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'd want to know how why creating instances of other classes with current database context instances as a parameter and using that db context causes this exception to be raised

> 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'

Imma use this sample code to show the problem

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public Controller(DbContext ctx)
    {
        dbContext = ctx;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string id)
    {
        var isValid = new otherClass(dbContext).Validate(id);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            return View("error");
        }

        var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        user.Age++;

        dbContext.SaveChanges(); // exception is being raised here. It is second .SaveChanges() here  

        return View();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class otherClass
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public otherClass(DbContext ctx)
    {
        dbContext = ctx;
    }

    public bool Validate(string id)
    {
        var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        user.ValidationAttempt = DateTime.Now;

        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return user.HasConfirmedEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: @John I didnt register anything related to DbContext.

Comment: @John Ops, sorry. ``services.AddDbContext<DbContext>
            (
               options => options.UseSqlServer(conn_string)
            );``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in an MVC fashion youre going to want a DbContext on a per request basis but when using threading more control through using blocks can be beneficial, an easy way to set that up would be something along the lines of

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly Func<DbContext> dbContext;

    public Controller(Func<DbContext> ctx)
    {
        dbContext = ctx;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string id)
    {
        using(var cntx = dbContext())
        {
        var isValid = new otherClass(cntx).Validate(id);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            return View("error");
        }

        var user = cntx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        user.Age++;

        cntx.SaveChanges();  

        return View();
    }
    }
}
```

that essentially resolves a new DbContext per using block - and since each thread is then handling its own DbContext - shouldnt have any issues

Comment: I thoguth that "per request" means "per every instance of controller"

Comment: btw. shouldnt be there ``using(var cntx = new dbContext())``?

Comment: @Joelty Yeah sorry, slightly poor wording on my part initially - generally a dbContext per instance of the controller is correct - though in your case as you're making use of threading then having a more direct control of context lifetime by using using blocks can be more beneficial to avoid threading issues - and if youre passing in a `Func` to the constructor then it wouldnt need the `new` keyword as the `dbContext()` is a shorthand for `dbContext.Invoke()` which just news up a DbContext using the fun

Comment: sounds cool, but how did you register it? on the other hand: I've been trying to creating new instance of ``dbContext`` basing on ``dbContextOptions`` in constructor of ``otherClass``, but it does not save data to db :/

Comment: @Joelty since it just using `Func` it should just be registered in the same way as a normal DbContext  so the `services.AddDbContext<DbContext> ( options => options.UseSqlServer(conn_string) )` you used earlier without `Func` should just work.

Comment: Weird, because he has problems with handling it. ``no service have been registered for type Func[dbContext]``

Comment: @Joelty ahh, if youre just using default Microsoft DI you might need it to be `services.AddTransient<Func<DbContext>>(x => () => x.GetService<DbContext>());` something along those lines to use `Func` correctly. Im too used to using Autofac / other DI's where they essentially take care of it under the hood for Funcs